# How to change border width of JTextarea in java

Tags: java, border, jtextarea

How to change the border width? I want a lighter border.

Below is my try

```
// Set border
Border border = BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
textarea.setBorder(BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(border, BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5)));
```

[image: JTextarea border width]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `LineBorder` of the text area is 1 pixel wide.

The JScrollPane also has a LineBorder 1 pixel wide.

Don't add the `LineBorder` to the textarea. Just use the `EmptyBorder`.